# Не создаются переменные в WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Только начал осваивать WebStorm. Буду признателен за помощь.
Почему у меня не создается переменная при данном написании кода в WebStorm:

`const upButton = 1;`

со следующей проблемой

> Unused constant upButton

Answer (score 1):

Почему вы решили, что она не создается? В сообщении сказано, что константа "не используется".
Проще говоря, создать вы ее создали, но далее по коду ни разу ее не запрашивали.